# How to toggle case of Entire string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to toggle case of entire string. 
I am able to do for characters, not for string.

```
DECLARE @Char AS VARCHAR(1)
SET @Char='a'
IF ASCII(@Char)>=97 AND ASCII(@Char) <=122
PRINT UPPER(@Char)
IF ASCII(@Char)>=65 AND ASCII(@Char) <=90
PRINT LOWER(@Char)
```

How, I can change case for entire string?
For Ex. "AbCdE", I want to change it to "aBcDe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating functions:

First make function for one character:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToggleChar
(
@Char VARCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CHAR(ASCII(UPPER(@Char))+ASCII(LOWER(@Char))-ASCII(@Char))
END
```

Then, create function for string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToggleCase
(
@Str VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ResultStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ResultStr=''
WHILE ( @Str<>'')
BEGIN
SET @ResultStr=@ResultStr + [dbo].[ToggleChar](@Str)
SET @Str= SUBSTRING(@Str,2,LEN(@Str))
END
RETURN @ResultStr
END
```

Now, use this function to toggle string.

```
SELECT dbo.ToggleCase('AbCdE') AS ToggleString
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(10) = 'SaMplE'
DECLARE @Count INT = 1 
WHILE @Count <= LEN(@Name)
BEGIN
    SET @Name = STUFF(@Name, @Count, 1,
                CASE 
                    WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Name,@Count,1)) BETWEEN 97 AND 122 THEN 
                        UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Name,@Count,1))
                    WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Name,@Count,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN 
                        LOWER(SUBSTRING(@Name,@Count,1))
                END)
    SET @Count = @Count + 1
END

SELECT @Name
```